# In What criteria should I use Web Method for Ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, webmethod

I am getting confuse, when I look at to learn about ajax. So many of them using in a different way. For example they are using **webservice,WebMethod, or server side**

> I know what is the purpose of webservice and where we have to implement. But I don't about web method. I saw some of stack overflow links. But still unclear.

I retrieve data from server using server side code, Then what will be the **difference between WebMethod and server side code**

Thanks

Comment: In asp.net, a webmethod is simply a method in your webservice's service side code.  The webservice is a collection of webmethods.

Comment: @freedomn-m can we create webMethod in normal webform?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax or jQuery Ajax, `$.ajax()`, is used to call a service or api over http asynchronously from the client side code. one of the parameters used in this method is the url which accepts the api or service url to which the request has to be made.

In classic ASP.net, you can also specify a name of a method that resides in your code behind which returns you the data to the client side from the server side code usually written in C# or VB.net. such methods have to be declared as web methods in the server side so you can make ajax calls to them from the client side so that they will treat them as service.

Please let me know if this makes sense. Below are some links that could also help you understand better.

[jQuery Ajax API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[Calling Web Methods from Ajax](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Comment: Can we create webmethod in normal form (ex: webform.aspx) file?.

Comment: web methods are written in C#, so if you want to write a web method in an aspx file, you can do so inside a script tag. For example:  `<script runat="server">[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
} </script>`

Comment: If we can write a `webmethod` inside the aspx page. Then What will be the difference of webservice's and aspx's webmethod?.

Comment: writing a web method in an aspx page will help you treat that method as a service.That DOES NOT mean its an entire web service which can serve other applications. writing a 'web service' exclusively depends upon what type of web service you want - an older .asmx based web service or the relatively new WCF web service. I strongly suggest you go through the links i sent earlier to write 'only' web methods in aspx pages. To understand web services as a whole - you can use the link below - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm